# Is it possible to distribute the haartraining processing?

Tags: linux, opencv, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, openmp

Is it possible to distribute the processing of haartraining across many machines?  Or would it be possible to divide the positive and negative images into different haartaining sessions and then somehow combine the haar classifer in the end.

I am planning on using EC2 for the processing.  Would it be possible to use the OpenMP with EC2?  Would it be less expensive to use one of the cluster GPU instances?

Thanks for your help,
Chris